# Leaf vein extraction in Opencv and applying in ml

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I want to extract leaf veins and use them in machine learning process, but I don't know how to do it right.

I've tried with sobel and get quite good results.

code:

```
  Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(3, 3), 0, 0);
  Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);      
  Mat Sx = new Mat(); Mat Sy = new Mat();
  Mat absSx = new Mat(); Mat absSy = new Mat();
  Imgproc.Sobel(image, Sx, CvType.CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, Imgproc.BORDER_DEFAULT);
  Core.convertScaleAbs(Sx, absSx);
  Imgproc.Sobel(image, Sy, CvType.CV_16S, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, Imgproc.BORDER_DEFAULT);
  Core.convertScaleAbs(Sy, absSy);
  Core.addWeighted(absSx, 0.5, absSy, 0.5, 0, image);
```

images:

[1](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/188/16c0.jpg)
[2](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9868/auyf.jpg)

Many depends on image resolution and quality, but is there better approach?

How to use these information in machine learning? 
How to transform this graphical data to a form appropriate for classifiers?

I've tried only using pixels data in classifaction, but outcome was not good.

Comment: I can refer you to a paper on contour/shape descriptors, if you'd like.

Comment: Ok it would be great, but this paper is free?

Comment: Yes. 

http://vis.uky.edu/~cheung/courses/ee639_fall04/readings/shapeReview.pdf