# Leaf veins detection using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv 2.4 and I am implementing in python. I want to find angle between leaf veins and its midrib. I have an image of a leaf -

[image]

After some processing like gaussian difference, binarization and noise removal, so far I am able to get leaf veins and midrib like this -

[image]

Now I am lost what to do next. I am unable to get any equation from this image. I tried post processing image using erosion and dilation like this -

[image]

[image]

I tried hough line detection after edge detection to get lines but it did not give satisfactory results. I read [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/best-way-of-segmenting-veins-in-leaves) that ridge detection may help me but I am not able to find any ridge filters in opencv.

Also following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301692/leaf-vein-extraction-in-opencv-and-applying-in-ml) was not much of help.

Any suggestions regarding further improvement are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Maybe [skeletonize](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) gives better results.

Comment: can you explain your target result? Is the result ok and you want to create some graph-like information from it? Or do you want to fill the gaps? Is it ok to not detect the leaf veins at the top? Or just general improvement in any way? Did you try line segment detection on your first image?

Comment: @Micka I need to find angle between every vein and midrib. May be representation of veins as line segments will help so our primary focus is this part. Gap filling is not required. It is ok if some veins skip. Suggestions for general improvements might open new possibilities for solution. Hough line detection was not helpful. Other feature detection methods were also not that much of help.

Comment: try `line segment detection` (LSD): http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d73/classcv_1_1LineSegmentDetector.html

Comment: Is is possible that you start with a colour image? To me it looks like you first need to get a better segmentation of midrip and veins which seems hard to achieve with your sample image.